# AngularJS: pass ng-model to function

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have around 40 input fields and all of them share the same logic for applying ng-class. So, instead of repeating the logic in ng-class I decided to define a function and call it like this:

```
<input ... ng-model="modelProperty" ng-class="GetHighlightingClassByNumericValue(modelProperty)" />
```

Considering that I have more than 40 input fields, I cannot copy and paste this because the model property is different. I'm wondering if there's a way to pass the ng-model value to the function.

Comment: why not putting all models in an array and use `ng-repeat`??

Comment: Hmm is $modelValue exposed in this manner, or is that only when you expose ngModelController in a custom directive?

Comment: I have a table with 40 columns, each column has an input binded to a different model property. I want to avoid having to call that function specifying the model property.

Comment: You could create a custom directive that sets the class based on the input value.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to use ng-class because it's a built-in feature.

Comment: @SeanLarkin If you look at  [the ng-class directive source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngClass.js#L3), it doesn't link to the `ngModelController`. Creating a sibling directive that observes `$modelValue` and updates the `ng-class` attribute seems the way to go.

Comment: Yeah or you could expose the $modelValue to scope in a custom directive that requires `ngModel`. But at that point you might as well just add a custom `ng-model` attribute that binds to `ng-model` via isolate scope and add it to you template.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to do:

```
.directive('modelToClass', modelToClassDirective);

function modelToClassDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: { ngModel: '=' },
    template: '<input ng-class="doSomethingWithInputModel(ngModel)" ng-model="ngModel" />
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you use it? are you able to use this directive in different input fields with different styles or attributes?

Comment: You described that the `GetHighlightingClassByNumericValue(modelProperty)` function is what generates a class? Where does that function live?

Comment: The function is declared in the same controller.

Comment: Could that function be moved to an injectable? And injected into this new directives controller?

Comment: I don't think it would make sense as it is a simple function that returns a CSS class based on a numeric value.

Comment: Ahh I see fair enough. I suppose then that function could live in the directives controller so that function is accessible in the inputs scope.

Comment: That's right. I need to avoid repeating over and over again the name of the binded property that I'm passing to the function. I thought it was gonna be possible to say ngModel or $this.value but it's not.

Comment: Regardless I hope that gave you somewhat of an answer you were looking for.